# How to add background image through css in django?

Tags: html, css, django

How to get the path to work so it shows the background image through css?
If it could be done with a relative path then how?

right now with this code, the background image is not being displayed.

Thanks for any help.

```css
/*mobile view*/
.index-banner {
    background: url('static/mysite/images/home.svg') no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;

}
```

```html
{% block content %}
    <section class="index-banner">
        <h2>Test<br>Condiitons</h2>
        <h1>lorel ipsum</h1>
        <h1>sdfjls upueh ndsfoi bbownl</h1>
        <img src="{% static 'mysite/images/home.svg' %}" class="mysite-img" style="display: none;">
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: not exactly an error, it's not displaying the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out the way,
so if you have your settings.py set to STATIC_URL = '/static/'
then background: url('/static/movies/images/home.svg') no-repeat;
should work,
what I was missing was a pre'/' before the static